# How do I change Google Chrome's touchpad gestures to go back using 2 fingers left-to-right?

Tags: google-chrome, touchpad, gestures, mouse-gestures

Google Chrome is set to go backwards a page by swiping two fingers right to left, but I find that backwards and the opposite of what it is on iPhone. How do I change the setting to use left-to-right 2 finger gesture to go backwards? I tried searching the settings for 'gesture' and 'touchpad' (`chrome://settings/?search=touchpad`) but it didn't find anything. I looked in the Windows touchpad settings, but it doesn't give 2 finger gesture settings, and the animation effect with the arrow appears to be coming from inside Google Chrome.

Windows 10

Answer (score 2):

Disable the history overscroll thing here:
[chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation](http://chrome://flags/#overscroll-history-navigation)

For me this revealed Win10's default swipe actions which makes it switch apps, you disable that in the "Gestures" in System Settings.

Comment: THANK YOU - this worked for me. Simple and exactly what I wanted. +1